# JS works on CodePen but not locally

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to get a JS slider to work. I'm using Brackets as my code environment.

I have tried creating a local .js file and putting

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="my.js"></script>
```

line in `<head>`

I have also tried just putting only `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">` in `<head>` and then putting all of the script code within a `<script>` tag in `<head>`.

CodePen for that:

https://codepen.io/hiarooo/pen/zYNboJq

As you can see, the slider doesn't function properly.

However, I have noticed that if I simply put the code in the `JS` box of CodePen (I have commented it, but you can try uncommenting it to see what I mean) then the Slider functions perfectly.

What is wrong with the way I am doing things? I do not understand.

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Did you check the console for any error messages?

Comment: Impossible to say, since I don't have access to CodePen from work (one reason why I think questions like these should be off topic), but likely because the code depends on certain elements already having been loaded into the DOM. Putting the script into the head means the DOM for the body hasn't been loaded yet. Wrap the code in `$(function () { ... });` or put the script just before `</body>`.

Comment: Thank you @HereticMonkey, it was indeed that the order was messed up. Putting at end of closing body tag works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Crypter | Upload01</title>`enter code here`
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Sans:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="my.js"></script>-->
    
  
    
</head>
  
  
<body>
   <section class="section-slider">
        <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Neucha' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


<div id="wrapper">
   
      
        
      <div id="slider-wrap">
          <ul id="slider">
             <li data-color="#1abc9c">
                <div>
                    <h3>What is cat</h3>
                    <span>it is a cat</span>
                  
                </div>                
                <i></i>
             </li>
             
             <li data-color="#3498db">
                <div>
                    <h3>Slide #2</h3>
                    <span>Sub-title #2</span>
                </div>
                <i class="fa fa-gears"></i>
             </li>
             
             <li data-color="#9b59b6">
                <div>
                    <h3>Slide #3</h3>
                    <span>Sub-title #3</span>
                </div>
                <i class="fa fa-sliders"></i>
             </li>
             
             <li data-color="#34495e">
                <div>
                    <h3>Slide #4</h3>
                    <span>Sub-title #4</span>
                </div>
                <i class="fa fa-code"></i>
             </li>
             
             <li data-color="#e74c3c">
                <div>
                    <h3>Slide #5</h3>
                    <span>Sub-title #5</span>
                </div>
                <i class="fa fa-microphone-slash"></i>
             </li>
             
             
          </ul>
          
           <!--controls-->
          <div class="btns" id="next"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></div>
          <div class="btns" id="previous"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></div>
          <div id="counter"></div>
          
          <div id="pagination-wrap">
            <ul>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!--controls-->  
                 
      </div>
  
   </div>
    
    </section>

      <script>
    //current position
var pos = 0;
//number of slides
var totalSlides = $('#slider-wrap ul li').length;
//get the slide width
var sliderWidth = $('#slider-wrap').width();


$(document).ready(function(){
    
    
    /*****************
     BUILD THE SLIDER
    *****************/
    //set width to be 'x' times the number of slides
    $('#slider-wrap ul#slider').width(sliderWidth*totalSlides);
    
    //next slide    
    $('#next').click(function(){
        slideRight();
    });
    
    //previous slide
    $('#previous').click(function(){
        slideLeft();
    });
    
    
    
    /*************************
     //*> OPTIONAL SETTINGS
    ************************/
    //automatic slider
    var autoSlider = setInterval(slideRight, 3000);
    
    //for each slide 
    $.each($('#slider-wrap ul li'), function() { 
       //set its color
       var c = $(this).attr("data-color");
       $(this).css("background",c);
       
       //create a pagination
       var li = document.createElement('li');
       $('#pagination-wrap ul').append(li);    
    });
    
    //counter
    countSlides();
    
    //pagination
    pagination();
    
    //hide/show controls/btns when hover
    //pause automatic slide when hover
    $('#slider-wrap').hover(
      function(){ $(this).addClass('active'); clearInterval(autoSlider); }, 
      function(){ $(this).removeClass('active'); autoSlider = setInterval(slideRight, 3000); }
    );
    
    

});//DOCUMENT READY
    


/***********
 SLIDE LEFT
************/
function slideLeft(){
    pos--;
    if(pos==-1){ pos = totalSlides-1; }
    $('#slider-wrap ul#slider').css('left', -(sliderWidth*pos));    
    
    //*> optional
    countSlides();
    pagination();
}


/************
 SLIDE RIGHT
*************/
function slideRight(){
    pos++;
    if(pos==totalSlides){ pos = 0; }
    $('#slider-wrap ul#slider').css('left', -(sliderWidth*pos)); 
    
    //*> optional 
    countSlides();
    pagination();
}



    
/************************
 //*> OPTIONAL SETTINGS
************************/
function countSlides(){
    $('#counter').html(pos+1 + ' / ' + totalSlides);
}

function pagination(){
    $('#pagination-wrap ul li').removeClass('active');
    $('#pagination-wrap ul li:eq('+pos+')').addClass('active');
}
        

    
    </script>

</body>
```

Try putting this way it works fine,because If you have code in your JavaScript that alters HTML as soon as the JavaScript file loads, there won't actually be any HTML elements available for it to affect DOM yet, so it will seem as though the JavaScript code isn't working, and you may get errors.Thanks :)